# How to filter files/directories according to permission and owner(tree command)

Tags: linux, command-line, tree

I use tree command to get files and directories under the /usr path,

> tree -pgufi /usr

Does it have a way to filter files/directories under this path according to several conditions(1 and 2 and 3)? 
e.g.,

> 1. file permissions=777
> 2. file owner is not root
> 3. file extension name is .so

Answer (score 1):

`tree` offers no filtering outside of file names, however it offers to display the owner and permissions of the files it displays with its `-u` and `-p` flags.

I would therefore enable these flags and pipe the result to a tool that will implement the filters :

```
tree -P *.so -up /usr | grep -v "root\s*]" | grep "\[.rwxrwxrwx"
```